# Как вернуть Graphics на прежнюю позицию

Tags: c#, графика, transform

При прокрутки trackBar объект Graphics g сдвигается вправо на 1.1F, если ползунок trackBar уйдёт в начальную позицию, то графика так же будет в начальной позиции. А мне нужно чтоб графика сдвигалась и влево и вправо

```
public Form1()
            {
                InitializeComponent();
                trackBar1.Scroll += trackBar1_Scroll;
            }

    private void trackBar1_Scroll(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                if (g != null)
                {
                    if (trackBar1.Value == 0) g.ResetTransform();
                    else g.ScaleTransform(1.1F, 1.0F);
                    tree.VisualiseTree(g);
                }
            }
```

Comment: Если вам надо влево и вправо, зачем вы масштабируете? `ScaleTransform`